# CodeBlocks throwing exception c0000005 APPCRASH on C++ code

Tags: pointer-to-member, virtual-inheritance, crash

Hello everyone first question here, but I get a lot of help from reading your responses now I have an issue that is getting the best of me.

I have a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "room.h"
#include "area1.h"

using namespace std;

void game_engine();

int main()
{
    game_engine();

    cout << "The end" << endl;

    return 0;
}

void game_engine()
{

    area1 nw;
    nw.welcome();

};
```

I also have an ADT base class called room and a child class called area1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "room.h"
#include "area1.h"

using namespace std;

area1::area1()
{
    this->description = "You are now in the North-West corner of the island. You have water to the North and the West, and this area is hard to navigate because of all the vegetation.  I hope you find something that you need. ";
    this->name = "NORTHWEST";
    this->odds = 25;
    this->random = 100;
    this->visited = false;
}

void area1::welcome()
{
   cout << name << endl;
   cout << description << endl;
}

void area1::treasure()
{

}

void area1::navigate()
{

}

area1::~area1()
{
    delete north;
    delete east;
    delete west;
    delete south;
}
```

What I don't understand is why it is crashing when all I am doing is calling a simple function from main, that calls a function in my area1 class.  No parameters are passed and the output is correct in the console for the function calls, but it crashes before it returns to main to call output "the end" .  I have done similar stuff without error quite often so this one is driving me nuts.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I took a shot and tried to compile and run in visual studio 2013, funny thing is it works fine in VS2013, maybe there is a bug/setting issue in code::blocks.  First time I experienced anything like this.

Comment: I suspect that your code is crashing when nw goes out of scope at the end of game_engine(). Where are `north, west, east and south` being set? What is your C++'s behavior if you `delete` a variable that has not yet been set?

Comment: That sounds logical, I am added the delete statements because I keep being hit on not clearing pointers and objects in my destructor, but I am not sure what that means when I thought that destructors would clear up any class objects automatically when exiting.  And I am not using NEW anywhere.  Still learning there I guess.  AS for the question on the game_engine() it has grown and now their is a member function that takes 4 pointer arguments that sets the "local" class pointers to the correct values for north, west, east and south.  used to navigate sort of like an expanded linked list.